# When $\mu(X)=\infty$, example for $f_n$ converge a.e but not converge in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

When $\mu(X)=\infty$, Can anyone give an example for  $f_n$  converge a.e, but not converge in measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure.

$$f_n = 1_{[n,n+1]}$$

Then $\mu(\{ x : \left| f_n(x) \right| \geq 1\})  = 1$ for every $n$;  but $f_n \rightarrow 0$.